# How to make cache data(on redis) to expire on basis of last access?

Tags: caching, spring-boot, spring-cache, spring-data-redis, redis-cache

I have spring micro-service application which using redis-server for cache store.
Using RedisCacheManager Api. In this we have option to set "**setDefaultExpiration**". Because of that rediscachemanager calculating expiry from first access of annotated method(**@cacheable**).

I want to calculate expiry time from last access of cacheable method not from first access.
Google library has given direct method to achive this:
In **CacheBuilder** we have method called **expireAfterAccess**
[CacheBuilder API](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#expireAfterAccess(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

We can use this when we want to use **google gauva server**. But in my application I have to use redis server for cache because of my centralised cache server requirement.
I checked RedisCacheManager class and didn't find a way to achive this.
How I can achieve this feature in redis-cache-server.
Below code for creating RedisCacheManager bean:

```
@Bean
RedisCacheManager cacheManager() {
    final RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(
            redisTemplate());
    redisCacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
    redisCacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(redisExpireTime);


    return redisCacheManager;
}
```

Comment: That's a Redis setting: https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache

Comment: @mp911de  I think we need to configure some functinality in  spring framework. Because evict request for cached data coming from application.

Comment: Redis supports only unconditional expiry after time. There's no relation to expiry after access. Spring Data Redis lets you defining an expiry that is set after write. (Expiry after write)

Comment: @mp911de Yes, I know redis support only "expiry after write". But I am looking for solution of "expiry after access" in spring data Redis. Thank you for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by customizing the cacheResolver , but it seems inefficient.

```
public class MyCacheResolver extends SimpleCacheResolver {

@Autowired
private RedisTemplate<Object, Object> template;

public CustomCacheResolver(CacheManager cacheManager) {
    super(cacheManager);
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends Cache> resolveCaches(CacheOperationInvocationContext<?> context) {
    if (context.getOperation() instanceof CacheableOperation) {
        DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer discover = new DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer();
        CacheableOperation op = (CacheableOperation) context.getOperation();
        String[] ps = discover.getParameterNames(context.getMethod());
        EvaluationContext ctx = new StandardEvaluationContext();
        for (int i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
            ctx.setVariable(ps[i], context.getArgs()[i]);
        }
        ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        String redisKey = parser.parseExpression(op.getKey()).getValue(ctx, String.class);
        String prefix = getCacheNames(context).iterator().next();
        long time = template.getExpire(prefix + ":" + redisKey);
        if (time > 0) {
            template.expire(prefix + ":" + redisKey, 300L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }
    return super.resolveCaches(context);
}
}
```

in my case ,every cache hit will automatically refresh the cache ttl to 300 seconds.
then inject the cacheResolver to configuration class,

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {
    @Bean("customCacheResolver")
    @Override
    public CacheResolver cacheResolver() {
        return new CustomCacheResolver(cacheManager());
    }

 @Bean
 public RedisCacheManager cacheManager() {
     //define your cacheManager here
 }

}
```

i hope it's clear,English is not my native language.